# How can I diff a file with a specific revision in Git?

Tags: git, diff, revision, magit

I don't know if Git has the concept of a revision.

I'd like to diff the current working copy with an older version of it (not necessarily the last commit).

It would be great if it could be done inside Emacs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've no idea about doing this inside Emacs, but:

```
git diff rev1..rev2
```

will do what you want for the whole repository. You can then add to that:

```
 git diff rev1>..rev2 path
```

`path` can be an absolute path to a file, or a path to a directory, so you can diff subtrees.

If you're looking to diff the working copy - just specify revision 1:

```
git diff rev1 path
```

The revision codes can be special names, for example, `HEAD^..HEAD` means last to current, or their SHA-1 values from the logs.

Comment: Are there commands to show revision history? because I can't even tell which revision I want.

Comment: How would it be changed to diff between two different paths from two different revisions?

Answer (score 1):

To do this in Emacs (using magit) you can:

1. From a magit buffer press `d` to open up the `diff` menu
2. Press `r` to select the range of commits to use in the diff. Alternatively, you can highlight a range of commits and they will automatically be selected.

If you only want to diff certain files, you can also use the `--` option to select which files will be included in the diff.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to diff revisions with Emacs [built-in package `vc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Old-Revisions.html).

`C-u C-x v D` (`M-x vc-root-diff` with a prefix argument) allows to diff any two revisions of the whole tree.

`C-u C-x v =` (`M-x vc-diff` with a prefix argument) allows doing the same for the current [fileset](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-VC-Editing.html) (which can be roughly defined as a collection of marked files).