# How do I use git diff aganst older commits?

Tags: git

```
git diff
```

shows the difference between the working files and the index, that is staged for the next commit.

How do you get the diffs for older commits? for example if you want to see what happened 3 commits ago with a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to diff a file with specific revision in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341546/how-to-diff-a-file-with-specific-revision-in-git)

Comment: that is nort a duplicate, if you don't know the rev numbers, it is hard to get the diff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since most things in git such as branches, tags, etc are really just pointers  to individual commits (which have SHA's), I think of git diff as

```
$ git diff sha1 [sha2]
```

This can be as literal as:

```
$ git diff 1e2aa76 c5b022f9
```

to show different between two states

You can also use 'relative' addressing with comparisons such as:

```
$ git diff HEAD HEAD~10
```

to compare the current HEAD of the branch with the state 10 commits ago.

You can combine relative and other methods and use of HEAD, e.g.

```
$ git diff 3947535 HEAD~3
```

or

```
$ git diff origin/master HEAD~3
```

or

```
$ git diff HEAD origin/HEAD~3
```

Other uses:

You can compare to the most recent (top) of master by using the word master,e.g.

```
$ git diff c5b022f9 master
```

You can compare to the latest master which you fetched (but perhaps didn't merge) with

```
$ git diff origin/master c5b022f9
```

You can also do all of the above against a specific file

```
$ git diff 1e2aa76 c5b022f9 Gemfile
$ git diff HEAD HEAD~10 Gemfile
$ git diff 3947535 HEAD~3 Gemfile
$ git diff origin/master HEAD~2 Gemfile
```

or directory, e.g.

```
$ git diff HEAD origin/HEAD~3 assets/
$ git diff c5b022f9 master assets/
$ git diff origin/master c5b022f9 assets/
```

and you can compare against the HEAD of the current branch by giving only one SHA, e.g.

```
$ git diff 1e2aa76 Gemfile
$ git diff HEAD~10 Gemfile
$ git diff origin/HEAD~3 assets/
$ git diff a_feature_branch assets/
$ git diff origin/master c5b022f9 assets/
```

fyi I'm using abbreviated SHA's such as c5b022f9,which has 8 digits, because they are unique enough in this repo with that many digits.  This can be easier to use than

```
git diff 17ce78cfcddb161c5e95f38270153a2fcdbd8019 a67a9e0e9a1aa39cfe2ee85730cd3499ad2edb65
```

Answer (score 2):

Changes since last commit: `git diff HEAD`

What happened 3 commits ago with file: `git diff HEAD~4 HEAD~3 file`

Answer (score 1):

A bit cryptic with the tilde, but this compares the current state of `file` with one, two, three, and four commits ago:

```
git diff HEAD~1 file
git diff HEAD~2 file
git diff HEAD~3 file
git diff HEAD~4 file
```